# Decimal.ToString not working if the value is zero

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have following code-

```
Label1..Text = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("col1") ?? 0).ToString("#,#.####", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

here, I am displaying the sum of 'col1' onto a label.
I am checking `x.Field<decimal?>("col1")` for null values

the problem is, if the value of a column is something like 1234, it displays properly, but if `x.Field<decimal?>("col1")` is null then it takes the value as ZERO and nothing displays on the label.

It seems like toString ignores the value if it is zero and returns nothing.

Please help

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you can just have `.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("col1"))` instead of using `??`, that will give you the same result, replacing `null` with `0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use format `"#,0.####"` That will show `0` for 0 values and `1,234` for `1234`

```
Label1.Text = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Sum(x => x.Field<decimal?>("col1") ?? 0)
                 .ToString("#,0.####", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You should see: [Custom Numeric Format Strings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> "0" - Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.